# How to change textField user-interaction according to condition in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, user-interaction

I have two textfields called toDateTextField and fromDateTextField

my need is  `if fromDateTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true` then if i tap on toDateTextField then it has to show  toast and should not open datepicker

**with this code if i tap initially on `toDateTextField` then datepicker is not opening but it is not showing toast.. how to show toast initially if i tap on `toDateTextField`**

**and if i initially tap on `fromDateTextField` then its showing toast message and then datepicker is coming**.. how to solve this two issues

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

toDateTextField.isEnabled = false
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

if fromDateTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {


       toDateTextField.isEnabled = false
    self.view.makeToast("Please select from date")


    } else {
       toDateTextField.isEnabled = true
}
}

//this is datpicker done button 
@objc func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

toDateTextField.isEnabled = true

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let arr = [fromDateTextField,toDateTextField]
    let current = arr[sender.tag]
    if let datePicker = current?.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
        current?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        current?.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

how to solve this two issues.. please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen if you initially tap on `toDateTextField` because you  have set its `enabled` property to `false` in `viewDidLoad` method.

And you will get the toast message as soon as you start modifying `fromDateTextField` because it is empty at the beginning.

To solve that, you need to do some modifications in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` so that it detects which textField is currently being changed and do what you want accordingly.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    if textField == toDateTextField {
        if fromDateTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
            self.view.makeToast("Please select from date")
            toDateTextField.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

And to enable `toDateTextField` you need to add the following:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == fromDateTextField {
            toDateTextField.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

---

Note: You need to set `delegate` of both textFields to self in your `viewDidLoad` for this solution to work properly.

Comment: where did u set `toDateTextField.isEnabled = false`

Comment: updating that now @anySwift

Comment: with this code `toDateTextField.isEnabled` always becomes `false`.. even there is text in  `fromDateTextField.text`  .. i just checked.. any solution plz

Comment: can you let me know what the output of `print(fromDateTextField.text?.isEmpty)` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` @anySwift

Comment: print(fromDateTextField.text?.isEmpty) initially its true after date added then becomes false still not able to add date in toDateTextField  bcz its enabel false

Comment: just updated my answer, check that again @anySwift

Comment: could u answer here.. i got stuck here from long..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073096/unable-to-set-today-date-as-datepicker-minimumdate-with-three-textfields-in-sw?noredirect=1#comment122079240_69073096